# 「ら」 in 「平たいら」meaning

Tags: grammar, meaning, nuances

What does 「ら」 means in word 「平たいら」 based on word 「平たい」? Word taken from anime "Non non biyori Repeat" and means the names of Triops (animals): 「ひらたいらさん」.

Comment: ひらたいらさん is probably also a parody of [はらたいら](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%81%AF%E3%82%89%E3%81%9F%E3%81%84%E3%82%89)さん.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

平 can be read a few different ways.  ひら is a common *kun'yomi*.  Another one is たいら, more commonly spelled 平ら with the ら as *okurigana*.  The たいら reading itself derives from prefix た- (as in たやすい) + ひら.  The た- prefix is described in some dictionaries as simply 「語調を整える」 ("adjusts the tone"), but it might come from た as the oldest known reading for 手 ("hand").

Both ひら and たいら mean "flat".  Combining the two into a name ひらたいら could suggest something very flat.  I'm not familiar with the anime *Non non biyori Repeat*, but Triops is also known in English as a ["tadpole shrimp"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triops), and this appears to be [カブトエビ](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%AB%E3%83%96%E3%83%88%E3%82%A8%E3%83%93) in standard Japanese.  These look a bit like a cross between a [horseshoe crab](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horseshoe_crab) and a shrimp or lobster.